# Empty Na in dataFrame columns

Tags: python, dataframe

df

```
  Letter    city    state
0   A        NYC    NY
1   B        Na     CT
2   C        LA     Na
3   D       Tampa   FL
4   E        Na     Na
5   F       Dallas  TX
6   G       Denver  CL

df['city']=df['city'].str.replace("Na"," ")
df['state']=df['state'].str.replace("Na"," ")
```

df

```
    Letter  city    state
0     A     NYC     NY
1     B     CT
2     C     LA  
3     D   Tampa     FL
4     E     
5     F   Dallas    TX
6     G   Denver    CL

df.isnull().any()
Letter    False
city      False
state     False
dtype: bool
```

How to empty Na to become:

```
Letter  False
city    True
state   True
```

Comment: Could you format your question and add the data in a way it can be copied and pasted directly into the editor.

Answer (score 2):

Starting with your original `df`, you can just do:

```
df.eq("Na").any()
```

Alternately, starting from the second `df`, after you replace `Na` with empty string, replace the empty strings with `NaN`:

```
import numpy as np

df.replace('', np.nan).isnull().any()
```

Both produce:

```
Letter    False
city       True
state      True
dtype: bool
```